# Current culture that has been set in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, culture, dayofweek

I set the culture in web.config in globalization section. The resource file loads correctly (for translated words). But when I want to show day of week it doesn't work based on the culture in web.config instead it uses the server culture.

How can I get the day of week based on culture that has been set in web.config not web server culture?

(again: I don't have any problem with resource file.)

The culture settings in web.config:

```
<system.web>
        <globalization
             fileEncoding="utf-8"
             requestEncoding="utf-8"
             responseEncoding="utf-8"
             uiCulture="ar"
             culture="ar"
          />
```

The code that shows day:

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( "ar" );
var day = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName( DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek );
dayOfWeekLbl.Text = day;
```

I set the culture in my C# code and it works. But I want that the code to use the culture from web.config.

I didn't write any code for resource file and it works with the setting in web.config.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code from your web.config where you set the culture.

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config settings are correct and should work. It seems that you have the culture set somewhere else in your project. Look for something like this:

- A function that is setting the culture in your code. The `InitializeCulture()` function is commonly used for that purpose.
- The assembly attributes. Example `[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")]`.
- The page directive. Example `<%@ Page Culture="en-US" UICulture="en-US" %>`

If you find any of these, delete them and try again to see if that resolve the problem. Of course, in the case of `InitializeCulture()` function, it can be needed for other purposes, so you'll have to modify it instead of deleting it.

Comment: There is no `InitializeCulture()` and `<%@ Page Culture="en-US"` and just one `AssemblyCulture("")` and it's for fckeditor, and it has nothing in quotations, just `AssemblyCulture("")`.

Comment: OK, but there must be some code that is changing the culture of the thread. Search in your entire solution for `culture` and see if you can find anything.